# how to rationalise code in order to add style to openlayers code mish-mash

Tags: javascript, openlayers

(I considered posting this to codereview.stackexchange.com, but openlayers.org's "Ask a question" link leads here, so I'm posting here.)

My code successfully draws a map, puts some SVG markers on it and overlays a GPX track. Now I would like to change the GPX track colour to make it more distinguishable from the map but all attempts (based on googled examples) are failing; there's no error message - though I wouldn't know where it would appear -, it's just that all attempts to style the track are resulting in the track not being displayed.

Here's the code:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>picrenamer3 - SAM_5772.JPG</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>
            svg#bullet {
                max-height: 22px;
                max-width: 22px;
            }
        </style>
  
        <script>
            var map;
  
            function updateClipboard(text) {
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function() {
                    /* clipboard successfully set */
                }, function() {
                    /* clipboard write failed */
                    alert('failed to write to clipboard (hint: are you serving this file over https?)');
                });
            }

            function initialize_map(lat, lon, zoom, trackfile) {
                map = new ol.Map({
                    target: "map",
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                                url: "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                            })
                        })
                    ],
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat]),
                        zoom: zoom
                    })
                });

                map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
                    var coordinates = evt.coordinate;
                    var p = map.getView().getProjection();
                    var cord = ol.proj.toLonLat(coordinates, p);
                    updateClipboard(cord[1].toFixed(6) + ',' + cord[0].toFixed(6));
                });

                if (trackfile != '') {
                    gpxTrackVector = new ol.source.Vector({
                        url: trackfile,
                        format: new ol.format.GPX()
                    });
          
                    var gpxTrackLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        source: gpxTrackVector,
                    });
                    map.addLayer(gpxTrackLayer);
                }
            }
  
            function add_layer_with_marker(lat, lng, col, cx, cy) {
                var svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="40" height="40" id="svg2"><circle cx="' + cx + '" cy="' + cy + '" r="7.5" id="c2" style="fill:' + col + ';stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.5" /></svg>'
                var mysvg = new Image();
                mysvg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + escape(svg);
  
                var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: new ol.source.Vector({
                        features: [new ol.Feature({
                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
                        })]
                    }),
                    style: new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon({
                            img: mysvg,
                            imgSize:[40, 40]
                        })
                    }),

                    /*
                     *  Stop markers totally obscuring markers at same place.
                     */
                    opacity: 0.6
                });
                map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
  
    <body onload="
       initialize_map(50.125819, 12.528039, 10.000000, '/home/alexis/sieben-fluesse-simplified.gpx');
       add_layer_with_marker(50.125819,12.528039,'#0000ff', 23, 17);
       add_layer_with_marker(50.125819,12.528039,'#ffffff', 23, 23);
    ">
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 80vh;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody advise me about how to rationalise the OpenLayers code here? Am I making any obvious errors regarding mixing OpenLayer versions? If I can correct those points, then I think I can probably google how to do the track styling or find an example that works on my code. Many thanks!

The rest of this post is some notes about the above code.

The above code is identical to what I'm running. I'm serving it using Python's SimpleHTTPServer (which I switched to when I realised file://-loaded JS can't write to the clipboard) so the path the GPX file in the initialize_map() call ('/home/alexis/') works for me and is shown on the map as a pale thin turquoise line, which is hard to distinguish from the map beneath it. Hence wanting to change the track's colour.

The above code is mashed together googled examples (one for displaying markers, one for displaying tracks, one for getting the location, one for writing text to the clipboard, etc), which - for all I know - might have been based on difference OpenLayers versions or used different approaches to programming with OpenLayers. But the result is that - due to my own lack of knowledge about Javascript and OpenLayers - I've painted myself into a corner and am unable to successfully do my next bit of development (the track colour). Hence coming here for some advice regarding rationalising the code, which I think is a prerequisite to carrying on code development and carrying on learning OpenLayers.

Unfortunately, for the purposes of writing this question, changing the path of the GPX to a URL doesn't show the track. In case it helps, the GPX file is available at https://www.pasta.freemyip.com/~alexis/sieben-fluesse-simplified.gpx.

Currently I'm bundling the SVG, CSS, HTML and JS all into one file. I'm doing this because the entire output is generated by a Python script, but I'm open to fanning it out into separate SVG, CSS, HTML and JS files.

Answer (score 1):

If OpenLayers is displaying the track in default style it should display any style as long as it is specified correctly, for example

```
var gpxTrackLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: gpxTrackVector,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'black',
            width: 8
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mike, that worked! But the wider question about rationalising my newbie code remains.